# Como capturar vários campos retornados de um Select usando Stored Procedure com parâmetros informados e colocar dentro de variáveis usando SqlServer?

Tags: delphi

-- Será retornado um conjunto de dados após informar 2 parâmetros, eu preciso pegar esse conjunto de dados e colocar em variáveis.

@ClienteTipoVeiculo VARCHAR(5),
@cdVeiculo int

as

```
if (@ClienteTipoVeiculo='Moto')
begin

    Select  mm.nmMarcaMoto, mom.nmModeloMoto, v.Renavam, v.Placa, v.AnoFabricacao,
            v.AnoModelo, v.Obs

    From Cliente C, TipoVeiculo tv, Veiculo v, MarcaMoto mm, ModeloMoto mom

        Where v.Vei_cdCliente           = c.cdCliente 
                and v.Vei_cdMarca       = mm.cdMarca    
                and v.Vei_cdModelo      = mom.cdModeloMoto              
                and tv.nmTipoVeiculo    = @ClienteTipoVeiculo and v.cdVeiculo=@cdVeiculo

end
 else if (@ClienteTipoVeiculo='Carro')      

    Select  mc.nmMarcaCarro, moc.nmModeloCarro, v.Renavam, v.Placa,
            v.AnoFabricacao, v.AnoModelo, v.Obs

    From Cliente C, MarcaCarro mc, ModeloCarro moc, TipoVeiculo tv, Veiculo v

        Where v.Vei_cdCliente           = c.cdCliente 
                and v.Vei_cdMarca       = mc.cdMarca    
                and v.Vei_cdModelo      = moc.codigo 
                and tv.nmTipoVeiculo    = @ClienteTipoVeiculo and v.cdVeiculo=@cdVeiculo  


  else
    raiserror ('Valor informado só pode ser Carro ou Moto',14,2)
```

Comment: O código que você tentou é realmente esse postado? Pois está um pouco longe, os selects precisam ser passados para algum componente `TQuery`... Ou é só um exemplo do que está tentando? Tente melhorar o exemplo como descrito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: O código é esse mesmo. Ao executar a Procedure no Sqlserver ele vai pedir 2 parâmetros que poder ser: 'Carro' ou 'moto' e o outro parâmetro será o código a ser pesquisado.


Ex: exec SPClienteVeiculo 'moto' , 1 


Retorno:   tv.nmTipoVeiculo,c.nmCliente ,Vei_cdCliente,Vei_cdMarca ,moc.nmModeloMoto,mca.nmMarcaMoto,Renavam,Placa ,V.Obs ,AnoFabricacao  ,AnoModelo


Esse retorno eu queria ter no DataSet para exibir nos Edit´s.

Comment: Ahhh agora entendi esse código é da procedure do SQL Server, pensei que esse código era do Delphi =S, está usando qual componente no Delphi? `TADOStoredProc`? Será que poderia mostrar o que já tentou no Delphi?

Comment: **Dica:** é melhor que edite sua pergunta, acrescentando essas informações ao invés de ficar correndo nos comentários, melhorar o título, explicação e tudo mais...